# ECharts: Add multiple labels to a single node

Tags: vuejs3, echarts

I am using Apache ECharts with a series of type 'graph' in my Vue3 project.

I am currently trying to find a way to add 2 labels to the same point on my graph (or at least a workaround). One label should be at the top and one at the bottom, regardless of the zoom level.

I made a little [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph&reset=1&edit=1&code=LYTwwgFghgTgLgOgM4QPYHcAyqoBMCWAdgOYAUAlANwBQAJAsQKZwBSAygPIBypAShxwAqAfQAKAQUEAJAAQBqGQHIA9LihwoyqEiTNV6zQBtGSALTB8umFABGxpAgBWSVIUUAaGQDMAroQDGcPiuMqTE1gAOEOQyAN7UMjKgkLCIEPi4jNh4RGRUCTLhUFEIhKiZDl6oMACiUP4QpL4BQSGkZZkx8YmJHYwIhraMhjIAvHEFPTIoGABcMn3IIMA2qIZs-ABejDIAfDIAzAAMkzIAvjSJZ_mJqBGthGMTU0FwxvPdUzJwjAAecPNFJgTDIALKWRjWOwmDynRJIHw2H7_QEAEUYXigPkMcBkgxAqB8cFhX2-d0BqzgcFQwBJX2MXgBShg-GIEGJpzO7lO1LWQQiHy5p2MTEIuHmAG04c9STJlMppsNGIFGLhQeVGICkLljHTSWoNPMiiV_OpGMRqvgTAhgMUmn5AsFHqQoF1pVMYMwfDBHlBSlBgIxLrLrtKzqcALrcqZQQj4W0PVHe9RO-YARgArEcjtGerH4ynXHVtSQAKoRA2apQARx8RCC_gAkoQOES9YqWSZJdLPqTCAGq0CQeCrLZ7O2XiAIoPjRAJz18YSmYoyoRGPPEgaoEbIhBShqkLnSYYiABrJA74p7k-Ec9Hr6mn4WzsXwq7hCP82Wkz3j04YDzHAMA-Iw3LSoMNjDB87reNUCY_DAkqKLEcARAAPmcHhKLESARPUjAYVhyHTjAp6ERGTioEQpCKAAOm45C_j0MzoIBwGgTBESoNqDyAkQ2qZIIdwbjIBBIBoARVjIGZMYkABukINlAhjiCexCEICFi4LguqyTIymshpSj-IwhAISJeHabkkoHJ4AAsUYwRAjCsuy6YyTB6AZHAEDuXpLINNBso9KhQXBT0Nj1Ke4SEmKYBrNUgKergIlTM5rlMgATDmMFTF5uA-fM2V6VcJUyCRp5heFMiRf40UwLFuDxYYiVKCAwwtegqU9OlbJMpmZWJPlhUyJmuXnGVuH4VV4W9W5o0ZuN4bBctXxCjBN6MGwcAgO8MrBf4CWIUoLjeiZ3X-N6Clrjo8xHAgBwwUKwWMMAUTaJYM2klUl2vooeCOPhAQgN1m3bbtVa9uFw2-aNJzVatpKIz0yMRgUFwFMk0DwMgzAcPcTqkHcDz5NclBAA). The red square at the top of a node does exactly what I want: it sticks to the top of the node on every zoom level. Now all I need is the yellow square to stick to the bottom, but I can't seem to make it work.

Best case scanario would be if I could add multiple labels to a single node. Is that even possible? Do you have other ideas how to make it work?

***EDIT:***

I adjusted the height of the labels spacer (see example) on [graphRoam event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.graphroam). It feels super hacky, but it does work for me:

```
function handleRoam(evt) {
  if (evt.zoom) {
    const customOptions = chart.value.getOption()
    const customOptionsData = customOptions.series[0].data

    //My scaleLimit is min 1, max 10
    const multiplier = customOptions.series[0].zoom > 6 ? 1.2 : 2
    customOptionsData.forEach((cod) => {
      if (cod.label?.rich) {
        //Dont ask how I got this formula, its trial and error and works for me
        cod.label.rich.space.height =
          customOptions.series[0].zoom * (15 + multiplier * customOptions.series[0].zoom)
      }
    })
    chart.value.setOption(customOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of is listening to the [`dataZoom` event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.datazoom) and adjusting the labels based on that.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens I had to use [graphRoam event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.graphroam), since I dont use dataZoom in my graph, but it does actually work (see my edit on the post). Feels very hacky though